# Wrong username given to my template when modifing the username

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a form that enabled the user to change his username. However, I want the user to enter his current password in order to change the username.

The modification works well and when the current password is wrong, it gives an error. However, the username of the user given to the template is the wrong one and so my text saying "Logged as XXX" in the header bar is wrong.

I mean that if the user enters "YYY" for the username, and the current username is "XXX", the message in the header bar will be "Logged as YYY" instead of "Logged as XXX".

I'm using app.user.username to display the name in my TWIG template.

Here is my controller code:

```
public function profileAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) 
    {
        if($user->getPlainPassword() != "")
        {
            $encoder  = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
            $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPlainPassword(), $user->getSalt());
            $user->setPassword($password);
            $user->setPlainPassword("");
        }
        $user->setPlainPassword("");
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_profile'));
    }

    return $this->render('CafauSecurityBundle:Security:profile.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Basically, in my form, the user can change his username and/or his password. Every time, he needs to provide the current password.

The problem is that when the form is not valid, the username given to the template is the one edited in the form and not the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve the problem:

1. Using a separate field for the new username, and
2. Using a form model.

#### Separate Field

You could create a separate field in your `User` class to hold the new username and copy it to the actual username after validation and before persisting — the same way you're currently doing with passwords.

#### Form Model

Basically, a [form model](http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/07/symfony2-famous-ozmerks-form-model-pattern/) is an object that embeds the actual model and those extra fields like `newUsername` or `plainPassword`. You would go this route if you don't want to clutter the actual model class with these extra fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went for the first solution even if I think that the second one is cleaner. But for my case, it was easier and not really important.